# Calculating the orthonormal frame of a metric in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, tensors, differential-geometry, development

Let us have a given a general metric (like say [Kerr metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric#Boyer%E2%80%93Lindquist_coordinates)) of which I want to find the orthonormal coordinates *by developing a general code in Mathematica*. One of the reliable method to do this (by hand and thus often tedious) is by using the [Gram-Schmidt Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), as done as an example in [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2423648/how-to-find-orthonormal-frame-of-given-metric).

So is there any way to develop such a general (all-purpose) code?

Comment: Could you provide a "typical" input and desired result? As it stands this is on the vague side, at least for non-experts.

Answer (score 1):

The eigensystem of the 5d example of a Riemann metric from the example contains 4th roots, so its of no algebraic use.

```
var = {x, y, z, w, t}
dvar = {dx, dx, dz, dw, dt}
```

$g(\text{x$\_$},\text{y$\_$},\text{z$\_$},\text{w$\_$},\text{t$\_$})=g()=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 t^2+y^2+1 & w y & t & 0 & -y \\
 w y & t^2+y^2+1 & 0 & t & -w \\
 t & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & t & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -y & -w & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
 g[]==g[]\[Transpose]
  True
```

Forget about tangent vectors. The metric is  a symmetric 2-form, a symmetric bilinear  map of two arguments in the tangent space. Since symmetric products

$dx\otimes dy + dy\otimes dx $
of 1-forms are orderless, Einsteins notation as polynomials of second order was sucsessful.

```
 ds/;ds^2 =(dvar.g[]).dvar


 dw (dw+dx t)+dz (dz+dx t) +
 dt (dt-dx w-dx y) +
 dx (dw t-dt w + dx w y + dx (1+t^2+y^2)) +
 dx (dz t-dt y + dx w y + dx (1+t^2+y^2))

NumberForm[locbase[1., 2., 3., 4., 5.] = locbase[] = 
Eigenvectors[g[1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]] // Chop, 2];

MatrixForm[locbase[]]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0.69014 & 0.703495 & 0.0905001 & 0.0922514 & -0.110001 \\
 0.699674 & -0.677431 & 0.157504 & -0.152497 & 0.0589961 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.298142 & 0.596285 & 0.745356 \\
 -0.0504759 & 0.214865 & 0.183821 & -0.782485 & 0.55246 \\
 0.177806 & -0.00384752 & -0.91887 & 0.0198833 & 0.351642 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

The generated basis is orthonormal, the rows constitute the new basis of 1-forms with unit metrics

```
  IdentityMatrix[5]==(locbase[].locbase[]\[Transpose] //Round)
 True

dvar . locbase[] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0.177806 \text{dt}-0.0504759 \text{dw}+1.38981 \text{dx} \\
 -0.00384752 \text{dt}+0.214865 \text{dw}+0.0260641 \text{dx} \\
 -0.91887 \text{dt}+0.183821 \text{dw}+0.248005 \text{dx}+0.298142 \text{dz} \\
 0.0198833 \text{dt}-0.782485 \text{dw}-0.060246 \text{dx}+0.596285 \text{dz} \\
 0.351642 \text{dt}+0.55246 \text{dw}-0.051005 \text{dx}+0.745356 \text{dz} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
 Rule@@@({du/@Range[5], dvar.locbase[] }\[Transpose])


  {du[1]->0.177806 dt-0.0504759 dw+1.38981 dx,
  du[2]->-0.00384752 dt+0.214865 dw+0.0260641 dx,
  du[3]->-0.91887 dt+0.183821 dw+0.248005 dx+0.298142 dz,
  du[4]->0.0198833 dt-0.782485 dw-0.060246 dx+0.596285 dz,
  du[5]->0.351642 dt+0.55246 dw-0.051005 dx+0.745356 dz}
```